# How to have helm / helmfile install the most recent chart version from a repo?

Tags: kubernetes, repository, kubernetes-helm, nexus, helmfile

I am testing helm packaging & helm package installations, and I have pushed several versions to my helm repository (Sonatype Nexus). These are the versions that I have pushed:

- version 1.0.0 / appVersion 1.0.0
- version 1.0.1-RC / appVersion 1.0.1-RC
- version 1.0.2-RC / appVersion 1.0.2-RC
- version 1.3.0-dev-RC / appVersion 1.3.0-RC
- version 1.3.0-staging-RC / appVersion 1.3.0-RC
- version 1.3.0-dev-RELEASE / appVersion 1.3.0-RELEASE

Now when I do

```
helm upgrade --install myRepo/myChart
```

I will get version 1.0.0 installed. I can, however, do

```
helm upgrade --install myRepo/myChart --version 1.3.0-dev-RC
```

and it will install that version 1.3.0-dev-RC just fine.

Same issue for `helmfile`. Given this helm file:

```
releases:
- name: myChart
  chart: myRepo/myChart
  version: ">=1.0.0"
```

When `apply`ing, I will also get version 1.0.0 deployed.

Why is this? I would assume that helm will install the most recent version if I don't specify one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version numbers with hyphens are [semantic versioning](https://semver.org) pre-releases (§9).  The [`helm install` documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/) notes

> [Helm] will install the latest stable version of that chart until you specify '--devel' flag to also include development version (alpha, beta, and release candidate releases), or supply a version number with the '--version' flag.

Helmfile has similar rules on using stable versions only, or has a `devel: true` option paralleling `helm install --devel`.

If you want the latest not-necessarily-release version, then you can use these options

```bash
helm upgrade --install --devel myRelease myRepo/myChart
```

```yaml
releases:
- name: myChart
  chart: myRepo/myChart
  devel: true
```

Note that `--devel` and `--version` can't be usefully combined, and `--devel` is equivalent to setting `--version '>=0.0.0-0'`.  Also note that, by the semver rules, `1.3.0-dev-RC` is less than version `1.3.0`; so if you need any pre-1.3-or-later version, but not a 1.2 release, you need a syntax like

```bash
helm upgrade --install --version '>= 1.3.0-0' ...
```